# UML Representation of XACML

Tags: uml, xacml, magic-draw

I've read many of the XACML questions and answers, which have been remarkably helpful, especially the links provided in many of the answers. But I haven't found what I was looking for, namely UML Class diagrams that represent the various interactions of the XACML components of PDP, PIP, Context Handler and the rest. Can  anyone point to such a thing? The answer to a prayer would be a MagicDraw representation, but that's too much to hope for.

Answer (score 2):

A class diagram would not show the interactions of XACML components. A component diagram, sequence diagram, or communication diagram would. If you want a class diagram of the policy language, the core specification has one. If you want a class diagram of the request / response, I wrote one for the JSON/XACML spec and it is available inside.

#### EDIT

## Class Diagram of the XACML Policy Language

[image: XACML Policy Language Class Diagram]

## Class Diagram of the XACML Request / Response

#### Request

[image: JSON XACML Request Class Diagram]

#### Response

[image: JSON XACML Response Class Diagram]

## XACML Architecture Diagram

[image: XACML Architecture]

## Data Flow Model

This comes from the XACML 3.0 standard document and is © OASIS. It is also available [online](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html).
[image: XACML Data Flow Model - taken from eXtensible Access Control Markup Language (XACML) Version 3.0 - Committee Specification 01 - 10 August 2010]

Comment: Thanks..."available inside" what?

Comment: OK, strictly speaking a class diagram does not show interactions, but relationships, (Wikipedia: a CD "describes the structure of a system by showing the system's classes, their attributes, operations (or methods), and the relationships among objects."  Yes, I have read the spec. Yes, I have Googled. I was hoping to find something that included methods. Something with real detail.